# Returning abstract type in base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

In a design of a class hierarchy, I'm using an abstract base class that declares various methods that the derived classes would implement. In a sense, the base class is as close to an interface as you can get in C++. However, there is an specific issue. Consider the code below which declares our interface class:

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual Interface method() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface {
public:
    virtual Implementation method() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Of course, this wouldn't compile, because you cannot return an abstract class in C++. To get around this problem I'm using the following solution:

```
template <class T>
class Interface {
public:
    virtual T method() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface<Implementation> {
public:
    virtual Implementation method() { /* ... */ }
};
```

This solution works and is all fine and dandy, however, to me, it doesn't look very elegant, because of the redundant bit of text which would be the parameter for interface. I'd be happy if you guys could point our any other technical issues with this design, but that is my only concern at this point.

Is there any way to get rid of that redundant template parameter? Possibly using macros?

**Note:** The method in question has to return an instance. I'm aware that if `method()` returned a pointer or a reference, there would be no issue.

Comment: The idiom you are aplying is called [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern). I guess you could replace class declaration with macro like `#define DERIVE_TEMPLATE_BASE(Derived, Base) class Derived : public Base<Derived>`, but it looks extremely ugly and will probably confuse your editor. Bottom line - yes, there is a redundancy, but it's well-established and recognizable idiom.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: That doesn't seem so bad. If it's a recognized idiom, then I can just assume it won't be too unfamiliar to the users of the "interface", correct?

Comment: Also note, that (in this example at least), there's no point to making the calls virtual, as CRTP required the most derive type to be known to use the base type.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's an interesting effect. What about the destructor?

Comment: As long as you don't call the destructor of a `Interface<Implementation>` then it doesn't matter.  And you won't, because there's no reason to have a `std::vector<Interface<Implementation>>` instead of `std::vector<Implementation>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Interface::method()` cannot return an `Interface` instance without using a pointer or reference.  Returning a non-pointer, non-reference `Interface` instance requires instantiating an instance of `Interface` itself, which is illegal because `Interface` is abstract.  If you want the base class to return an object instance, you have to use one of the following:

A pointer:

```
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual Interface* method() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface
{
public:
  virtual Interface* method() { /* ... */ }
};
```

A reference:

```
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual Interface& method() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface
{
public:
  virtual Interface& method() { /* ... */ }
};
```

A template parameter:

```
template<type T>
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual T method() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface<Implementation>
{
public:
  virtual Implementation method() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

While you can't return by *value* for obvious reasons, it's entirely OK to return pointers or references -- this is called "covariant return type", and it is a valid form of virtual function overriding:

```
struct Base { virtual Base * foo(); }
struct Derived : Base { virtual Derived * foo(); }
```

The point is that `Derived::foo()` is a genuine *override*, and not a base-hiding overload, because `Derived*` is is a pointer to a derived class of `Base`. The same applies to references.

In other words, if you have a `Base * p`, and you call `p->foo()`, you can always treat the result as a pointer to `Base` (but if you have additional information, such as that your class is in fact `Derived`, then you can use that information).

<sub>The opposite composition order, i.e. "contravariant argument types", is not allowed as part of C++.</sub>